# Combine 2 Mysql table regardless of any relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. For example table a and table b. They have no relation among themselves, but yet I need to bring all their data with one query. Union can not do it, as it does not work for different no. of rows and it can not be done with joins as there is no 'on' condition. So How do I do it ?

---

```
Table a
id     title 
x       b
c       d
s       z
```

---

```
Table b
id     title 
q       u
m       h
```

---

I need it something like this :

```
a.id    a.title    b.id    b.title
x        b           q       u
c        d           m       h   
s        z           null    null
```

Comment: Try this  hope this helps SELECT test_a.id, test_a.title, test_b.id, test_b.title FROM a test_a, b test_b

Comment: Have you tried UNION? It's the columns that matter, not the rows.

Comment: no, that doesn't work. Using comma like you mentioned produces left join. So that brings all table b data with each table a data.

Comment: union does not work, because i need 4 columns in my resulting table, but union always brings the common columns and if different columns are mentioned , mysql will show an error

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `INNER JOIN` and assign an id to each of your tables using `ROW_NUMBER`. See my query below:

```
SELECT A.id,A.title,B.id as id2, B.title as title2 FROM(
SELECT
     @row_number1:=@row_number1+1 AS RowNumber1,
     id,
     title
FROM TableA, (SELECT @row_number1:=0)AS x ORDER BY title) AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
     @row_number2:=@row_number2+1 AS RowNumber2,
     id,
     title
FROM TableB, (SELECT @row_number2:=0)AS y ORDER BY title) AS B
WHERE RowNumber1=Rownumber2
```

**[MY DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b733c/14/0)**